# How to fix the below C# error?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

How can I fix the below error? I'm using C#.

[image]

Comment: It is an empty string. It can be seen in `Auto` window.

Comment: And share code snippets instead sharing screenshots

Comment: do you really need to tag this with 3 different c# versions? ;)

Comment: You should use Double.TryParse()

Answer (score 0):

Check if you input string is a number. Also check your decimal separator. Try this if you are using comma.

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," }; 
decimal myDecimal = Decimal.Parse(string, nfi);
```

Comment: Should use TryParse instead of Parse.

Comment: Decimal disCp = Convert.ToDecimal (txtDiscountedCashPrice.Text);
 Int16 Qty = Convert.ToInt16 (txtQuantity.Text);
 Decimal TA = disCp * Qty;
 txtTotalAmount.Text = TA.ToString();